# Combining two loops

Tags: jquery, loops

I want to get this with looping 01 to 10 and a - j

I have the loops separate but don't know how to join them.

```
//A - Z
for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    var letterEnd = String.fromCharCode(i).toLowerCase();
}

//01 - 10   
var i;
for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
  var precedingZero = (i<10) ? '0' : '';
  var currentMenuClass = ".p" + precedingZero + i;
  var currentMenuSansP = precedingZero + i;

 $(currentMenuClass + 'a .plus_sign.plus' + currentMenuSansP).hide();
 $(currentMenuClass + 'a .minus_sign.minus' + currentMenuSansP).show();
```

The final should be as this with 01 to 10 and a - j

```
 $(.p01a .plus_sign.plus01).hide();
 $(.p01a .minus_sign.minus01).show();
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested loops.

```
var i;
for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
  var precedingZero = (i<10) ? '0' : '';
  var currentMenuClass = ".p" + precedingZero + i;
  var currentMenuSansP = precedingZero + i;
  for (var j = 97; j <= 112; j++) {
    var letterEnd = String.fromCharCode(j);
    $(currentMenuClass + letterEnd + ' .plus_sign.plus' + currentMenuSansP).hide();
    $(currentMenuClass + letterEnd + ' .minus_sign.minus' + currentMenuSansP).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barman I get an error. Chrome console: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .p01 .plus_sign.plus01

Comment: Sorry, missed one of the `i` that needed to be changed to `j` in the inner loop.

Comment: I should have seen that. Many thanks you helped my greatly